# Simultaneously training two CNN models

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I wish to train two CNN models in the same training loop where the input of the second model is the feature map generated by the forward pass on the first model.

```
def custom_training(inputd, x_train, y_train, x_val, y_val, n_epochs):

    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()

    ce_loss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=False)

    loss_train = np.zeros(shape=(n_epochs,), dtype=np.float32)
    acc_train = np.zeros(shape=(n_epochs,), dtype=np.float32)
    loss_val = np.zeros(shape=(n_epochs,))
    acc_val = np.zeros(shape=(n_epochs,))
    unet_model = tf.keras.Model(inputd, build_unet(inputd, 16))
    #ds_model = DS_module()
    n_batches = len(generator_train)
    print(n_batches)
    for epoch in range(n_epochs):
        
        epoch_loss_avg = tf.keras.metrics.Mean() # Keeping track of the training loss
        epoch_acc_avg = tf.keras.metrics.Mean() # Keeping track of the training accuracy
        for batch in range(n_batches):
            x, y = generator_train[batch]
            
            with tf.GradientTape() as tape: # Forward pass
                y_ = unet_model(x, training=True)
                loss = ce_loss(y_true=y, y_pred=y_)
                
        k = compute_K(y_)
        print(k)
        ds_model = tf.keras.Model(y_, DS_module(y_, k, num_class))
        
        
        
        
        grad = tape.gradient(loss, unet_model.trainable_variables) # Backpropagation
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grad, unet_model.trainable_variables)) # Update network weights

        epoch_loss_avg(loss)
        epoch_acc_avg(accuracy_score(y_true=y, y_pred=np.argmax(y_, axis=-1)))

    #generator.on_epoch_end()
    loss_train[epoch] = epoch_loss_avg.result()
    acc_train[epoch] = epoch_acc_avg.result()

    y_ = unet_model.predict(x_val) # Validation predictions
    loss_val[epoch] = ce_loss(y_true=y_val, y_pred=y_).numpy()
    acc_val[epoch] = accuracy_score(y_true=y_val, y_pred=np.argmax(y_, axis=-1))
```

Below are the content of the two models, which consist of Unet, and another convolutional model, which will take as input the feature map generated by the Unet model:

```
def build_unet(input_layer, start_neurons):
    # 128 -> 64

    conv1 = Conv2D(start_neurons * 1, (3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same")(input_layer)
    conv1 = Conv2D(start_neurons * 1, (3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same")(conv1)
    pool1 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(conv1)
    pool1 = Dropout(0.25)(pool1)

    # 64 -> 32
    conv2 = Conv2D(start_neurons * 2, (3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same")(pool1)
    conv2 = Conv2D(start_neurons * 2, (3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same")(conv2)
    pool2 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(conv2)
    pool2 = Dropout(0.5)(pool2)

    # 32 -> 16
    conv3 = Conv2D(start_neurons * 4, (3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same")(pool2)
    conv3 = Conv2D(start_neurons * 4, (3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same")(conv3)
    pool3 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(conv3)
    pool3 = Dropout(0.5)(pool3)

    # 16 -> 8
    conv4 = Conv2D(start_neurons * 8, (3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same")(pool3)
    conv4 = Conv2D(start_neurons * 8, (3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same")(conv4)
    pool4 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(conv4)
    pool4 = Dropout(0.5)(pool4)

    # Middle
    convm = Conv2D(start_neurons * 16, (3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same")(pool4)
    convm = Conv2D(start_neurons * 16, (3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same")(convm)

    # 8 -> 16
    deconv4 = Conv2DTranspose(start_neurons * 8, (3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding="same")(convm)
    uconv4 = concatenate([deconv4, conv4])
    uconv4 = Dropout(0.5)(uconv4)
    uconv4 = Conv2D(start_neurons * 8, (3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same")(uconv4)
    uconv4 = Conv2D(start_neurons * 8, (3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same")(uconv4)

    # 16 -> 32
    deconv3 = Conv2DTranspose(start_neurons * 4, (3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding="same")(uconv4)
    uconv3 = concatenate([deconv3, conv3])
    uconv3 = Dropout(0.5)(uconv3)
    uconv3 = Conv2D(start_neurons * 4, (3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same")(uconv3)
    uconv3 = Conv2D(start_neurons * 4, (3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same")(uconv3)

    # 32 -> 64
    deconv2 = Conv2DTranspose(start_neurons * 2, (3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding="same")(uconv3)
    uconv2 = concatenate([deconv2, conv2])
    uconv2 = Dropout(0.5)(uconv2)

    uconv2 = Conv2D(start_neurons * 2, (3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same")(uconv2)
    uconv2 = Conv2D(start_neurons * 2, (3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same")(uconv2)

    # 64 -> 128
    deconv1 = Conv2DTranspose(start_neurons * 1, (3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding="same")(uconv2)
    uconv1 = concatenate([deconv1, conv1])
    uconv1 = Dropout(0.5)(uconv1)
    uconv1 = Conv2D(start_neurons * 1, (3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same")(uconv1)
    uconv1 = Conv2D(start_neurons * 1, (3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same")(uconv1)
    feature_maps = Conv2D(start_neurons, (1, 1), activation='relu')(uconv1)
    return feature_maps
@tf.function
def DS_module(feature_map, prototypes, num_class):
    ED=DS1(prototypes, 16)(feature_map)
    ED_ac=DS1_activate(prototypes)(ED)
    mass_prototypes=DS2(prototypes, num_class)(ED_ac)
    mass_prototypes_omega=DS2_omega(prototypes, num_class)(mass_prototypes)
    mass_Dempster=DS3_Dempster(prototypes, num_class)(mass_prototypes_omega)
    pignistic=DM_pignistic(num_class)(mass_Dempster)
    pignistic=DS3_normalize()(pignistic)
    outputs = pignistic    
    return outputs
```

When I execute this code, i obtain the following error:
[Error message obtained](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjxhy.png)

This is the content of compute_k function, it executes PCA, Kmeans and Silhouette score on the feature map.

```
def compute_K(featureMap):

X = tf.reshape(featureMap, [featureMap.shape[0]*featureMap.shape[1]*featureMap.shape[2], featureMap.shape[3]])

pca = PCA(n_components=2)
principalComponents = pca.fit_transform(X)
principalDf = pd.DataFrame(data = principalComponents, columns = ['principal component 1', 'principal component 2'])

X = principalDf.to_numpy()
print(len(X))

#range_n_clusters = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
range_n_clusters = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
silhouette_avg_n_clusters = []

max_sillhouette = 0
max_k = 0
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 7))
plt.subplot(111)
for n_clusters in range_n_clusters:
    
    # Initialize the clusterer with n_clusters value and a random generator
    # seed of 10 for reproducibility.
    clusterer = KMeans(n_clusters=n_clusters, random_state=42)
    cluster_labels = clusterer.fit_predict(X)

    silhouette_avg = silhouette_score(X, cluster_labels)
    print("For n_clusters =", n_clusters,
        "The average silhouette_score is :", silhouette_avg)

    silhouette_avg_n_clusters.append(silhouette_avg)

    if (n_clusters == 2):
        max_sillhouette = silhouette_avg
        max_k = n_clusters
    if (max_sillhouette< silhouette_avg):
        max_sillhouette = silhouette_avg
        max_k = n_clusters

return max_k
```

Comment: Can you update your question with how you defined your model?

Comment: what are you using the `ds_model` that you are creating at each step?

Comment: `ds_model` is the second part of the model which input is the output of unet_model and a parameter k(which is calculated based on the  feature map generated by unet_model) through compute_K function. I don't know how I can do to avoid it creation at each step, it is not supposed to be created at each step.

Comment: Maybe try using `@tf.function` with your functions, especially with `build_unet()`

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).